# scrollView: how to create a pure auto layout scrollview with paging?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Can someone tell me what I did wrong here...
- pin the UIScrollView to its container view
- pin all subviews onto UIScrollView

After reading the Apple TechNote about it, I tried both hybrid method and pure auto layout method. The hybrid method using NIB works awful with paging, it looks like a big picture in a scrollview, rather than paged.

I then created the pure auto layout version in code, UIScrollView as subview of a UIView. This time the view stuck, and the UIImage is gigantic, like its full size:

```
    //scroll view
    if (self.scrollView == nil)
    {
        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

        [self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

        [self addSubview: self.scrollView];
        [self addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView(300)]|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:@{@"scrollView":self.scrollView}]];
        [self addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(300)]|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:@{@"scrollView":self.scrollView}]];
```

```html
-(void) createContentView
{
    
    for (int i=0; i<self.pageImages.count; i++) {
        
        UILabel* topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        topLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"topLabel %d", i+1];
        [topLabel sizeToFit];
        
        [self.topLabelArray insertObject:topLabel atIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:topLabel];
        topLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        

        UILabel* bottomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bottomLabel %d", i+1];
        [bottomLabel sizeToFit];

        [self.bottomLabelArray insertObject:bottomLabel atIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:bottomLabel];
        bottomLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        button.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button %d", i+1];
        [button sizeToFit];

        [self.buttonArray insertObject:button atIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        
        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
        
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        
            [self.pageViews insertObject:imageView atIndex:i];
        
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        NSDictionary* viewsDictionary = @{@"topLabel":topLabel,
                                          @"bottomLabel":bottomLabel,
                                          @"button": button,
                                          @"imageView": imageView
                                          };

        [self.scrollView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[topLabel]-(10)-[imageView]-(10)-[bottomLabel]-(10)-|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [self.scrollView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[button]-(10)-|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        
        if (i==0)
        {
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[topLabel]"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
            
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[imageView]"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
              [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[bottomLabel]-(10)-[button]"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
        }
        else if (i == self.pageImages.count)
        {
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[topLabel]-(10)-|"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[imageView]-(10)-|"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];

            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[bottomLabel]-(10)-[button]-(10)-|"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:viewsDictionary]];
        
        }
        else
        {
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[prevTopLabel]-(10)-[topLabel]"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:@{@"prevTopLabel": [self.topLabelArray objectAtIndex: i-1],
                                                                @"topLabel": topLabel
                                                                   }]];
            
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[prevImageView]-(10)-[imageView]"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:@{@"prevImageView": [self.pageViews objectAtIndex: i-1],
                                                               @"imageView": imageView
                                                               }]];
            
            [self.scrollView addConstraints:
             [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[prevButton]-(10)-[bottomLabel]-(10)-[button]"
                                                     options:0 metrics:nil
                                                       views:@{@"prevButton": [self.buttonArray objectAtIndex: i-1],
                                                               @"button":button,
                                                               @"bottomLabel": bottomLabel
                                                               }]];
        }
        [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:topLabel
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:imageView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  multiplier:1
                                  constant:0.0]];
        
        [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintWithItem:bottomLabel
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:imageView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                             multiplier:0.8
                             constant:0.0]];
 
 //        [self.scrollView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's a few things wrong here:

`else if (i == self.pageImages.count)`

This clause will never run, as your loop count is set to break when `i == self.pageImages.count -1`, here `for (int i=0; i<self.pageImages.count; i++)`.

Next

```
        [self.scrollView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[topLabel]-(10)-|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [self.scrollView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[imageView]-(10)-|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

        [self.scrollView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-(10)-[bottomLabel]-(10)-[button]-(10)-|"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
```

These will also produce invalid constraints, specifically `@"H:-(10)-[bottomLabel]....` is not pinning the furthest left constraint to anything. All visual format strings that connect views need to start or finish with a view. Either a subview (`[subview]`) or a superview (`|`). To fix this, you need to keep a reference to the previous pages label in the loop, and add that to the beginning of your VFL string. Something like this

```
   @"H:[prevBottomLabel]-(10)-[bottomLabel]....

   prevBottomLabel = bottomLabel;
   // Continue loop
```

Next:

```
   UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:i]]];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);

    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

This will not have the desired effect, as you can't manually set the frame, then switch on autolayout. Currently, the frame value is ignored, and the  height and width are set by the intrinsic content size of the image view, which will be the height and width of the image. If you want to set the height and width, you need to do it with constraints, as so:

```
   [imageView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imageView(200)]"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];

   [imageView addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imageView(200)]"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
```

That should give you some pointers, there may be other mistakes in there too but fixing these is a good place to start.

Comment: thank you for the explanation...it works now. I was trying different ways to make it work and the code was a bit messy (and wrong). I think the biggest issue I had was the VFL not ending with a UIView. I will take note of it. The other one was with the imageview sizing. Using auto layout, it looks like one could only use constraints to set the size. Noted too. Does one also set the scroll size (ie paging size here) with constraints, instead of frame? Setting scrollview frame worked for me in the past.

Comment: I also have a question if you could help me confirm: with paging, does scrollview anticipate each single page to be contained within an individual UIView? I know semantically it looks cleaner that way, and it probably is also a preferred way. But is it  absolutely necessary to add five UIViews, each containing UIImageView, labels and buttons, to the scrollview as subviews, and page that way?

Comment: To your first comment, I believe the paging size is defined by the width of the scroll views frame, so it snaps to a multiple of the width. The scrolling size is defined as a big as it needs to be to satisfy the constraints of it's content. You can think of this as the scrollviews contents pushing out to expand the scrollable area. This is why you have to have constraints running from edge to edge in an unbroken line for it to work properly.

Comment: To your second comment, the answer is no, you don't need to have each page as it's own UIView, as mentioned above, paging just causes the scrolling to snap to a multiple of the scrollviews frames width